# Term for choosing to believe a falsehood

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

I was wondering if there is a term when you choose to believe something even when you know it is likely untrue?

The concept I'm thinking of would differ from cognitive dissonance in that you're choosing a theory to believe, so there is no absolutely right answer.  Or when someone has a pet theory that has little or no evidence for or against.

Examples I would give that might fall into this might be believing horoscopes/star signs, one religion over another.

"I have a pet theory, that honestly is likely false, but I choose to believe it, and almost actively would prevent proving it wrong."  Is there a term to describe that belief, or the act of holding it?

Comment: Richard Dawkins chose "delusion" for the title of his book about why people persist in believing in gods.  I think Jane Austen preferred "willful self-deception".  Do you like either of those?

Comment: I suppose it’s sort of in between _blind faith_ and _autosuggestion_. I’m fairly sure there are several idioms and even single words that refer to doing this, but my mind is drawing a blank at the moment (a good sign that it’s bedtime) …

Comment: Or what about the psychologists' term "confabulation"?

Comment: Your question seems to be going of fin a number of directions.  Is it the belief itself, or the choice to belive it?  Is it a matter of the proposition being false regardless of the existence of evidence, being either true or false but lacking evidence, or being false and having evidence to the contrary?

Comment: Have you tried asking on psychology Q&A cogsci.stackexchange/com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another word that springs to mind is

[***doublethink***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/doublethink) from George Orwell's 1984 for accepting contradictions and falsehoods as a technique of [***self-indoctrination***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/indoctrination?s=ts), which itself is a good word I think.

Answer (score 5):

*[Self-deception](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/self-deception)* is the act of hiding the truth from yourself.

Comment: but you are not deceiving yourself if you 'know' that what you choose to believe is wrong. This person is not hiding the truth - he is actively promoting what he knows to be untrue.

Comment: but there is no hiding involved. The person is honest enough to admit that he 'chooses' to believe.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite one word but close enough, for people that really want to believe in something even though they don't think that it is true, we could say it's a "foolish hope" or a "fool".

For people like fortune tellers that doesn't actually believe what they were telling others to believe, we could call them a "hypocrite".

For people that actually truly believe their false pet theories, and doesn't in any bit doubted its falsity despite contradictory evidence, we could say they're "misguided" or "deluded".

Comment: Similar to a foolish hope, you can also say that you choose to remain in a ***fool’s paradise***.

Answer (score 3):

There is a phrase ***[wishful thinking](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wishful+thinking)*** used to describe a concept that is highly unlikely, but you would oh-so-hope *could* be true

> the attribution of reality to what one wishes to be true or the tenuous justification of what one wants to believe

Comment: this applies to 'wishing' that something is true - not quite the same as promoting what you 'know' to be false.

Comment: @user49727 While there is no requirement that the wisher know the falsity (or unlikeliness) of the aspiration, it is often the case that eventual disappointment is understood.

Comment: I was going to suggest this (+1). Although it is unclear whether the wishful thinker necessarily knows that the belief is false, in most cases where I have seen the phrase used it seems that it is a willful delusion rather than any expectation of truth.

Answer (score 3):

Way too complicated answers for a simple one word answer... and that would be 'denial'.

> From the Merriam-Webster Dictionary
>
> > 1: refusal to satisfy a request or desire
> >
> > 2a (1) : **refusal to admit the truth or reality** (as of a statement or charge) (2) : assertion that an allegation is false
> >     2b : refusal to acknowledge a person or a thing : disavowal

A close cousin would be 'delusional', which could also apply, and is in general a stronger form of denial.

> From the Merriam-Webster Dictionary
>
> > 1: the act of deluding : the state of being deluded
> >
> > 2a : something that is falsely or delusively believed or propagated
> >     b : **a persistent false psychotic belief regarding the self or persons or objects outside the self that is maintained despite indisputable evidence to the contrary; also : the abnormal state marked by such beliefs**

Comment: This question requires a complicated answer I'm afraid. OP has clearly indicated that the person 'knows' that what is believes is untrue. He is not looking for a 'psychotic'. And 'denial' is refusal to admit 'truth' not something you know to be untrue.

Comment: @user49727. I did not write the definitions for these words, and by definition, both these words could apply if a person still believes in what he knows to be not true.

Comment: Hi - I guess the point I was making was that both these terms imply delusion and psychosis in addition to obstinacy, and are therefore judgemental more than matter-of-fact descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

**Contrarian**

> [(noun)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contrarian) a person who takes an opposing view, especially one who rejects the
> majority opinion, as in economic matters.
>
> [(adj)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/contrarian) opposing or rejecting popular opinion; going against
> current practice:

You would be considered a contrarian if you believe that the earth is hollow.

Believing in astrology is a contrarian attitude within a scientice-oriented society.

Refusing to follow your parents' religion and following another religion might get you branded as a contrarian within your family.

Comment: but rejecting popular opinion doesn't necessarily imply that you are rejecting something that is untrue or not right...

Answer (score 2):

The examples you have provided of a person obstinately adhering to his beliefs in traditional customs and ideas describes a [***mumpsimus***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mumpsimus), a word with an interesting etymology.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single word, but I think the expression you want is "willfully self-deceived." I think it has precisely the meaning you're seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Cognitive dissonance - experienced by a person who simultaneously holds two or more contradictory beliefs, ideas, or values

Comment: Please cite your source for the definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implying that these deliberate falsehoods are all in the form of cultural beliefs only then I think [***conformism***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conformism?s=t) would fit. Unless I have completely misconstrued the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a word which refers to the state of departing from usual or accepted standards. The specific word is **deviance**.